# JWT components information

Tags: java, jwt, token, jhipster

```
    private static final Key secret = MacProvider.generateKey(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256);
    private static final byte[] secretBytes = secret.getEncoded();
    private static final String base64SecretBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretBytes);

    private static String generateToken(String subject, String issuer, String audience) {
        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");
        Date now = new Date();
        Date exp = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 30)); // 30 seconds

        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setId(id)
                .setIssuedAt(now)
                .setNotBefore(now)
                .setExpiration(exp)
                .setSubject(subject)
                .setIssuer(issuer)
                .setAudience(audience)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, base64SecretBytes)
                .compact();

        return token;
    }

    private static void verifyToken(String token) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(base64SecretBytes)
                .parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();

        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println("ID: " + claims.getId());
        System.out.println("Subject: " + claims.getSubject());
        System.out.println("Issuer: " + claims.getIssuer());
        System.out.println("Expiration : " + claims.getExpiration());
        System.out.println("Not Before : "+claims.getNotBefore());
        System.out.println("Audience :: "+claims.getAudience());
    }
```

I have web serves JHipster API and I wrote Java code to connect it and I know the JWT token have three components from JWT web site https://jwt.io/ 
 first Decoded

```
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

secound is PAYLOAD

```
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "iat": 1516239022
}
```

my issue in this part how we know sub,name and iat in JHipster API webserves ?

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE]

This answer is according to the io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt library

According to the documentation provided on their [github](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt#jws-read) page

```
Jws<Claims> jws;

try {
    jws = Jwts.parser()         // (1)
    .setSigningKey(key)         // (2)
    .parseClaimsJws(jwsString); // (3)

    // we can safely trust the JWT

catch (JwtException ex) {       // (4)

    // we *cannot* use the JWT as intended by its creator
}
```

`setSigningKey()` is the key you use to protect your JWT. With this key you van verify if your JWT is unchanged and valid.

The parseClaimsJws() is where you set your JWSString as parameter.

After that you should be able to iterate over the claims and read the values

[OLD]

This answer is according to the com.auth0:java-jwt library

In order to get you "claim" you have to decode you JWT. You can do this with the following code:

```
DecodedJWT decodedJWT = JWT.decode(JWTString);
String sub = decodedJWT.getClaim("sub").asString();
String name = decodedJWT.getClaim("name").asString();
String iat = decodedJWT.getClaim("iat").asInt();
```

If you also want to verify if the JWT is still valid you can do this by using the JWT verifier:

```
JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require("YOUR ALGORITHM").build();
DecodedJWT decodedJWT = verifier.verify(JWTString)
```

Comment: i get this problem - JWTString cannot be resolved to a 
  variable
 - DecodedJWT cannot be resolved to

Comment: JWTString should be your encoded JWT string that you want to decode. So in your case the name of that variable is "token". Use the value of "token" instead of JWTString

Comment: [error ][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8hnZ.png            i get this error

Comment: Can you provide me a image where I can also see your imports and which JWT library do you use?

Comment: in my main i write 
    String token = generateToken("Admin", "Issuer", "Audience");
         System.out.println("TOKEN :: "+token);
         verifyToken(token);   but i don't know the correct parameter in  generateToken function

Comment: Your not using the JWT library that http://jwt.io provides. I did a quick search to the library that you using. I'll update my answer to match your library.

Comment: i not understand what you mean!

Comment: in my main i call this function String token = generateToken("subject", "Issuer", "Audience")          how i know what is subject , Issuer and Audienve ?